# Conditional stage based on whether a stashed file exists

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to create a pipeline in Jenkins, where the first stage may or may not generate files to be stashed for later. I'd like to make the next stages conditional based on whether a stashed file exists. I'm not sure how to do this since the unstash step comes after the 'when' expressions.

Rough outline:

Stage 1: Run a script that could generate anywhere from 0-3 files (to be stashed and used as inventory files for Ansible)

Stage 2: If file1 exists, run playbook with file1 as the inventory

Stage 3: If file2 exists, run playbook with file2

and so on..

I've tried setting a variable in the environment block with the fileExists option, but that's going to evaluated before any stages run.

```
environment {
  FILE_EXISTS = fileExists './filename'
}
stages {
  stage ('Conditional Stage') {
    when {
      allOf {
        expression { params.FILE_EXISTS == true }
        expression { env.BRANCH_NAME != 'master' }
      }
    }
    steps {
      unstash 'files'
      sh 'ansible ... '
    }
  }
}
```

(Tried both params.FILE_EXISTS and env.FILE_EXISTS)

Also tried the 'when' expression inside the stage in a similar way.

```
stage ('Conditional Stage') {
  when {
    allOf {
      expression { fileExists './filename' }
      ...
    }
  }
  steps {
    unstash 'files'
    sh 'ansible ...'
}
```

Both methods skip the stage due to the conditional.

I'd like to avoid archiving the files, if possible, since they'll only ever be needed for the current build.

Has anyone been able to accomplish this, or am I missing something simple?

One additional note: the files will be stashed on a Windows slave, then unstashed on a Linux slave. This hasn't been a problem with the stash/unstash, but figured it was worth mentioning that the files will always unstash on a different slave than where they were stashed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a global variable i.e **def FILE_CREATED = 0**  and modify it in the middle of your pipeline, once a specific condition is met, in that case ensuring that a file exists and updating the value of FILE_CREATED from 0 to 1 (see the code below).

You can check later in a stage with the `when` directive the value of that variable by using `expression`.

The next pipeline has been tested and works well for that demo purpose, it runs the stage **Run some echo actions ONLY if a specific file exists** only if the file 
 '/tmp/demotime1' exist.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def FILE_CREATED = 0

pipeline {

    agent {
        label 'linux'
    }

    stages{

        stage('Show if file exists'){
            steps {
                echo "At first, var FILE_EXISTS value is: $FILE_CREATED"
                echo 'Now check if /tmp/demotime1 exists'
                echo '/tmp/demotime1 It should not exists on the very first execution'
                script {
                    def demofile = new File('/tmp/demotime1')
                    if (!demofile.exists()) {
                        println('That is expected, /tmp/demotime1 file has NOT been created yet')
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Force file creation and change env var'){
            steps {
                echo 'creating a file'
                sh """ echo 'Demo time file content here' > /tmp/demotime1 """
                echo 'At this time /tmp/demotime1 exists see:'
                sh """ cat /tmp/demotime1 """
                echo "Now let's change env var to true"
                script {
                    if (new File('/tmp/demotime1').exists()){
                        println('File exists and FILE_CREATED should be 1 now')
                    }
                    FILE_CREATED = 1
                }
                echo "Now FILE_EXISTS value is: $FILE_CREATED"
            }
        }

        stage('Run some echo actions ONLY if a specific file exists'){
            when {
                expression {
                    FILE_CREATED == 1
                }
            }
            steps {
                echo 'The file exists so I will do something original...'
                echo 'Hello World, the  $FILE_CREATED has been created'
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the detailed response!
Unfortunately this leads to a separate issue on my end. This is a multibranch pipeline so the scripts will always run in a sandbox. I get an error stating 'Scripts not permitted to use new java.io.File java.lang.String' - and any changes I've seen to workaround will be a headache, security approval wise.
Right now I'm living with the stages "succeeding" without an inventory file. I thought they would fail, so at least that's not the case.

Comment: Maybe you can consider to use shared libraries to code your very own custom steps for your stages, you won't have security issues with shared libraries, they are trusted (a jenkins admin configured them ) and don't need sandbox, more info here https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Comment: Good suggestion - I'll come back to that another day, as for now I'm just dealing with the stages completing successfully. I'll mark you response as the answer since it seems like it would work in most situations. Thanks again!